# Filtering Database query results with array from separate database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have a bunch of websites that are all pulling data from a single database. All of these are almost identical and built on CodeIgniter.

Each one then has a separate db with data specific to that site.

Universal Database:
TABLE 'courses' = 
Columns: id, course_name, price, external_link, tracking_link

Site Specific Database:
TABLE 'courses' = 
Columns: id, active, description

There is a pool of course and course data that each site pulls in from the Universal Database, but then each site can determine which of those courses are "active". I can get all the ids of the rows where "active" = 1 from the Site Specific database and pass them to an array.

But then I want to use the ids from that query as a filter on the Universal Database to pull that course data into various parts of the site.

Here is my model:

```
public function getActiveCourses() {

    $local_db = $this->load->database('local', TRUE);
    $universal_db = $this->load->database('universal', TRUE);       


    $activeCourses =    $local_db
                ->where('active', 1)
                ->select('id')
                ->get('courses');
    $activeList = $activeCourses->result_array();



    $allCourses =   $universal_db
            ->where('id', $activeList)
            ->get('courses');

    return $allCourses->result_array();

}
```

But I get the following error

```
 Error Number: 1054

 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

 SELECT * FROM (`courses`) WHERE `id` = Array

 Filename: /models/courses.php

 Line Number: 39
```

Line 39 is:

```
$allCourses =       $universal_db
            ->where('id', $activeList)
            ->get('courses');  <== Line 39

return $allCourses->result_array();
```

I've been searching and playing with this for hours and hours. Any help is mucho mucho appreciated.

New to CI and php so can provide any further details if necessary. Not sure off the bat, what is most needed.

Trey

Comment: Probably you are looking for `where_in()` when using on the universal db? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html you cannot pass an array to `where()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, $activeList is an array, but you need to provide a single value instead:

```
$activeList = $activeCourses->result_array(); // see, "result_array"
// here you're returning the row in array format (array ['id'] =>...)
$allCourses =   $universal_db
            ->where('id', $activeList)  // here are you using the whole array!
            ->get('courses');
```

**It should be this:**

```
$allCourses =   $universal_db
            ->where('id', $activeList['id']) // passing the specific array index
            ->get('courses');
```